# How do I prevent Windows tasks from automatically triggering after resuming from hibernate?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hibernate, windows-task-scheduler

I set up Windows tasks to automatically hibernate my computer if I forgot to turn it off or I'm on too late as a reminder to get off.

So for instance, in my settings I have:

```
Triggers
  Weekly At 11:00 PM every Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday Thursday of every week
Actions
  Start a program C:\Windows\system32\shutdown.exe /h
Settings
  (Unchecked) Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed

Triggers
  Weekly At 11:15 PM every Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday Thursday of every week
Actions
  Start a program C:\Windows\system32\shutdown.exe /h
Settings
  (Unchecked) Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed
```

If my 11:00 PM event triggers and I need to turn my computer back on at 11:20 PM, it will automatically hibernate my computer again and I have to resume it a second time, despite the fact that I have "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" unchecked. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Windows 7 Professional and can only be fixed by upgrading to Windows 10. I haven't tested this on Windows 8 so I can't say whether the issue exists there too.

It's worth noting that if, "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" is checked on Windows 10, this behavior will resume.